# Expression Blend Consolidate Path Function

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I'm using Expression Blend 4. I would like to be able to take a `Path` that I've manipulated via `ScaleTransform`, `RotateTransform`, `Height`, `Width`, etc., and somehow extract just the resulting geometry data.

For example, here is the `Path` that I've manipulated:

```
<Path x:Name="path" Data="M34.555819,-10.855642 L33.87765,10.694269 111.5,10.5 111.5,30.5 35.546387,30.836126 34.332857,52.291507 -24.919613,20.285166 z" Fill="White" Margin="12.624,48.361,717,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="19.77" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.5" ScaleX="0.5"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-45.19"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="-0.0091096941141897148" Y="-3.18742921035944"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
```

Now, from this `Path`, can I create a new consolidated `Path` where the manipulations and settings are built in to the `Path`'s geometry (data)? Producing something like without all of the transforms, etc.

```
<Path Data="<new data>" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple trick I use for that sort of thing, is to draw another small and simple `Transparent` `Path` over it, select both, then **Object->Combine->Unite** and you'll get the resulting new `Path` `Data` and that usually does the trick.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What a pain in the ace...  Seems you need to select the non-transformed layer first in order for the output to be non-transformed.  If you select the one with the transform first, it will combine them but still apply the transform to the combined output.